# What the easiest way to convert part of a vector to string?

Tags: c++, string, vector, type-conversion

I want to convert part of a vector to a string, I found this
`std::string myString(Buffer.begin(), Buffer.end());` (Buffer is the vector)

But here I converted the whole vector. What the easiest way if I want to skip first 5 chars of the vector and convert the rest? Like `''.join(Buffer[5::])` if it was python.

Comment: `std::string myString(std::next(Buffer.begin(), 5), Buffer.end());`? Be careful not to go out-of-range.

Comment: Why did you delete this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796973/calling-thread-is-inaccessible-wpf?noredirect=1#comment119834259_67796973 ?

Comment: @Enigmativity the question was deleted due to the fact that there were many similar questions. But your answer helped me, thanks.

Comment: It's good to keep those questions even if they are duplicates. Quite often a duplicate becomes the question people find when searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add your offset to `begin`.  Since a `vector` has random access iterators, you can just use

```
std::string myString(Buffer.begin() + 5, Buffer.end());
```

If you are not sure about what type of iterators your container is using, you can use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) like

```
std::string myString(std::next(Buffer.begin(), 5), Buffer.end());
```

which will handle all iterator types, it also may be an O(N) operation.

You also need to make sure that the size of the container is at least `5` before you do this otherwise you'll have undefined behavior if the container is too small.

Answer (score 3):

Like this for example:

```
if (Buffer.size() >= 5) {
    std::string myString(
        Buffer.begin() + 5,
        Buffer.end());
```

A more general approach that works with non-random access iterators as well (such as iterators of `std::list` for example):

```
    std::string myString(
        std::next(Buffer.begin(), 5),
        Buffer.end());
```

Or using ranges:

```
    auto subrange = Buffer | std::ranges::views::drop(5);
    std::string myString(
        std::ranges::begin(subrange),
        std::ranges::end(subrange));
```

Answer (score 3):

A safe (avoiding accesses out of bounds), general approach could be

```
std::string myString(std::next(Buffer.cbegin(), std::min(5, Buffer.size()),
                     Buffer.cend());  //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```